# Error: The FunctionImport 'StoredProcedureName' could not be found in the container 'EntityFileName'. Only after published to app service

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, azure-web-app-service

I am using a database-first approach to generate models in my project, these models are built from tables in an Azure hosted SQL database.

When I run this on my localhost, I can interact with Entity Framework in all of the ways I would expect, no problems. However, after I publish the application to my Azure App Service, none of my stored  procedures or models can be located in the container.

I get errors like:

> The FunctionImport 'StoredProcedureName' could not be found in the container 'ContainerName'.

I have verified that the connection string is formatted in the correct manner (it was created by the EF wizard anyway). Besides, this would most likely show an issue when running locally also I assume.

Other things I have tried:

- Deleting the models and stored procedures and rebuilding them in the `.edmx` file.
- Verifying the connection string locally and then in the `web.config` once up on the AppService.
- Clearing down the bin folder on the AppService.
- Restarting the AppService & Visual Studio.

Comment: Either yo9ur connection string is wrong and you are connecting to a different server (or database in server) or you have a credential issue and the StoredProcedure cannot be accessed from the credentials.   Best way of finding out what is wrong is open database with SQL Server Management Studio and check the log files in the explorer under Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out in this case, somebody had added a `web.config` on the App Service settings itself, which was overwriting the one in my websites root directory.

Removing this rogue entry fixed my problem.